# Formula with range how to add adding another row in that range

Tags: google-sheets, sum, max, match, sumifs

I have this complexed formula that I need to update manually every time I add a new row to that range:

```
=SUMIFS('actions!O3:O21,'actions!B3:B21,"buy",'actions!C3:C21,"UK")*-1+SUMIFS('actions!N3:N21,'actions!B3:B21,"buy",'actions!C3:C21,"UK")*-1
```

I wonder what is the best solution to handle dynamic ranges inside formulas without using app script?

Thanks

EDIT: I'm unable to do as the comment suggested because the last row is saved for sums.

EDIT 2: I created an example sheet [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ye0x7lArk0r0gzOZqQ4qaQID-lGFffXPxReLNTy3Gq8/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Have you tried changing `O3:O21` to `O3:O` for instance? (Same for all the other ranges) Or what exactly would you like to accomplish? Can you please share more details about this?

Comment: @ale13 I forgot to mention that the last row of the range is showing the sums of each column so using the whole column won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=SUMIFS(actions!O3:O, actions!B3:B, "buy", actions!C3:C, "UK")*-1+
 SUMIFS(actions!N3:N, actions!B3:B, "buy", actions!C3:C, "UK")*-1
```

### update 1:

if this formula is meant to be in the same row as the total sum row try:

```
=SUMIFS(INDIRECT("actions!O3:O"&ROW()-1), 
        INDIRECT("actions!B3:B"&ROW()-1), "buy", 
        INDIRECT("actions!C3:C"&ROW()-1), "UK")*-1+
 SUMIFS(INDIRECT("actions!N3:N"&ROW()-1), 
        INDIRECT("actions!B3:B"&ROW()-1), "buy", 
        INDIRECT("actions!C3:C"&ROW()-1), "UK")*-1
```

### update 2:

if you just want the whole range without the last row:

```
=SUMIFS(INDIRECT("actions!O3:O"&ROWS(A:A)-1), 
        INDIRECT("actions!B3:B"&ROWS(A:A)-1), "buy", 
        INDIRECT("actions!C3:C"&ROWS(A:A)-1), "UK")*-1+
 SUMIFS(INDIRECT("actions!N3:N"&ROWS(A:A)-1), 
        INDIRECT("actions!B3:B"&ROWS(A:A)-1), "buy", 
        INDIRECT("actions!C3:C"&ROWS(A:A)-1), "UK")*-1
```

or if the above won't do try:

```
=INDEX(
 SUMIFS(INDIRECT("actions!O3:O"&MAX(ROW(A:A)*(A:A<>""))-1), 
        INDIRECT("actions!B3:B"&MAX(ROW(A:A)*(A:A<>""))-1), "buy", 
        INDIRECT("actions!C3:C"&MAX(ROW(A:A)*(A:A<>""))-1), "UK")*-1+
 SUMIFS(INDIRECT("actions!N3:N"&MAX(ROW(A:A)*(A:A<>""))-1), 
        INDIRECT("actions!B3:B"&MAX(ROW(A:A)*(A:A<>""))-1), "buy", 
        INDIRECT("actions!C3:C"&MAX(ROW(A:A)*(A:A<>""))-1), "UK")*-1)
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the last row of the range is showing the sums of each column so using the whole column won't work.

Comment: here is a template sheet I created @player0: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ye0x7lArk0r0gzOZqQ4qaQID-lGFffXPxReLNTy3Gq8/edit#gid=0)

Comment: fixed @player0. [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ye0x7lArk0r0gzOZqQ4qaQID-lGFffXPxReLNTy3Gq8/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: what about now @player0? [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ye0x7lArk0r0gzOZqQ4qaQID-lGFffXPxReLNTy3Gq8/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: thanks for the answer but it isn't exactly what I meant. the question and example weren't accurate enough I'm trying to get that total sum in another sheet for dynamic range as we've seen and not in the sum line below the range so using ROW() won't help. @player0

Comment: @ReaB. answer updated, try now

Comment: update 2 seems to work great! thanks a lot!
is there a way to make ROWS(A:A) function reference another sheet (or is it called a tab)? @player0

Comment: I successfully added the sheet name and it works, once again thanks a lot! @player0

Comment: I tried to do the same logic using the INDIRECT for the total sum cell below the range and I'm getting circular dependency, any clue how to solve that?
=SUM(INDIRECT("actions!O2:O"&ROWS('actions'!A:A)-1)) @player0

Comment: @ReaB. indirect formula looks right

Comment: I'm receiving circular dependency error for using that formula: =SUM(INDIRECT("actions!O2:O"&ROWS('actions'!A:A)-1)) @player0

Comment: @ReaB. can you share a copy of your sheet with that error?

Comment: can you look at the example sheet I uploaded? cell F25 @player0

Comment: @ReaB. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UprDzbCelj9jg8Ep4_tnJ-eVfRthewGEj8GaynBmPTo/edit#gid=0